# Click event cannot be fired in HorizBar

Tags: winforms, teechart

I am using TeeChart for WinForm version: 4.1.2016.5122. But when the mouse is move to the series and click on them, the related event is not fired.
Has anyone ever met this problem?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    HorizBar bar = new HorizBar(m_barChart.Chart);

    bar.MultiBar = MultiBars.Stacked;
    bar.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    bar.BarHeightPercent = 100;
    bar.CustomBarWidth = 20;

    //Event registered below will not be fired up
    bar.Click += Bar_Click1;

    bar.Depth = 50;
    bar.DepthPercent = 50;
    bar.Marks.Visible = false;
    bar.Color = Color.Blue;
    bar.Add(i, 0);

    bar.Title = string.Format(" {0} {1}", i, i);
}

//Event registered below is not fired up
m_barChart.ClickSeries += M_barChart_ClickSeries;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below using TeeChart.Net v4.1.2016.5122, the ClickSeries fires without problems.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChart();
        }
        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                HorizBar bar = new HorizBar(tChart1.Chart);

                bar.MultiBar = MultiBars.Stacked;
                bar.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                bar.BarHeightPercent = 100;
                bar.CustomBarWidth = 20;

                bar.Depth = 50;
                bar.DepthPercent = 50;
                bar.Marks.Visible = false;
                bar.Color = Color.Blue;
                bar.Add(i, 0);

                bar.Title = string.Format(" {0} {1}", i, i);
            }

            tChart1.ClickSeries += TChart1_ClickSeries;

        }


        private void TChart1_ClickSeries(object sender, Series s, int valueIndex, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                this.Text = s.Title;
        }
```

Could you check again the code and confirm us if it works in your end?

Comment: Hi, I think I find the reason. When I try to set "m_tChart1.Aspect.View3D = true" the event will not be fired and even the cursor is not changed to hand. I think it maybe TeeChart`s regression, because in TeeChart.4.1.2012.9284 it works fine.

Comment: Hi Albert, I have checked again the problem, setting the view3D to true and I confirm when I use v4.1.2016.5122 the problem is produced. But, I would like inform you it is already fixed for latest TeeChart.Net v4.1.2017.02146. You can check it using our trial version, you find in the link below: https://www.steema.com/downloads/net

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks. I will have a try. But for now I will just avoid to set that property.